# str object has no attribute select

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

what is the problem? what should I do? I want to make a web crawling tool.
I am using BeautifulSoup to pick up.

```
def get_page(url):
    try:
        import requests
        import bs4
        import lxml
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
        return soup
    except:
        return ""


def get_all_target(page):
    list = []


for elem in get_page(page).select("a"):
    list.append(elem.get("href"))
return list


def union(p, q):
    for e in q:
        if e not in p:
            p.append(e)


def crawl_web(seed):
    tocrawl = [seed]


crawled = []
while tocrawl:
    page = tocrawl.pop()
    if page not in crawled:
        union(tocrawl, get_all_target(get_page(page)))
        crawled.append(page)
return crawled
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
File"<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 9, in crawl_web
File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_all_target
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Is there any mistake using "select" method  in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: you should use soup.find('a') or soup.find_all('a') , instead of select method

Comment: @AtsushiSakata, the problem seems that an exception is being raised when you run `get_page`, so this function returns an empty string.

Comment: ^^.  I am still new to Python but shouldn't import statements happen outside of a Try Except  at the top of your code? The indentation of def get_all_target(page):  looks off as well.